# Why does my INSERT INTO does not work well with NVARCHAR?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Here is my code with a stored procedure. The result table when `SELECT`ing does not show the `NVARCHAR()` type as intended but instead seems like `VARCHAR()`.

```
CREATE TABLE [User] 
(
    [UserId] int IDENTITY(1,1),
    [FirstName] nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    [LastName] nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    [Sex] varchar(6) CHECK([Sex] IN('Male', 'Female')) NOT NULL,
    [IdentificationNumber] varchar(20) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    [DOB] date NOT NULL,
    [Address] nvarchar(100) NOT NULL,
    [Email] nvarchar(100) NOT NULL,
    [Role] varchar(13) CHECK([Role] IN('Teacher', 'Student', 'Administrator')) NOT NULL,
    [PasswordHash] Binary(64) NOT NULL,
    [Salt] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    PRIMARY KEY ([UserId])
);
```

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [AddUser]
    (@pFirstName nvarchar(50),
     @pLastName nvarchar(50),
     @pSex varchar(6),
     @pIdentificationNumber varchar(20),
     @pDOB date,
     @pAddress nvarchar(100),
     @pEmail nvarchar(100),
     @pRole varchar(13),
     @pPassword nvarchar(50),
     @ResponseMessage nvarchar(250) OUTPUT)
AS
BEGIN
    IF @pSex NOT IN ('Male', 'Female')
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR ('Sex should be either Male or Female', 0, 1) 
        RETURN
    END
    
    IF @pRole NOT IN ('Teacher', 'Student', 'Administrator')
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR ('Role should be Teacher, Student, or Administrator', 0, 1)
        RETURN
    END
    
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    DECLARE @salt UNIQUEIDENTIFIER=NEWID()
    
    BEGIN TRY
        INSERT INTO [BeszeDB].[dbo].[User] (FirstName, LastName, Sex, IdentificationNumber, DOB, Address, Email, Role, PasswordHash, Salt)
        VALUES (@pFirstName, @pLastName, @pSex, @pIdentificationNumber, @pDOB, @pAddress, @pEmail, @pRole, HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', @pPassword + CAST(@salt AS NVARCHAR(36))), @salt)

        SET @ResponseMessage = 'Success'
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SET @ResponseMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE()
    END CATCH
END
```

```
DECLARE @ResponseMessage nvarchar(250)

EXEC [AddUser]
       @pFirstName =  'Trần Triệu',
       @pLastName= 'Trịnh',
       @pSex = 'Male',
       @pIdentificationNumber = '12345',
       @pDOB = '2000-09-29',
       @pAddress = '235 Đường Giải Phóng',
       @pEmail = 'minhhoangtrinh231@gmail.com',
       @pRole = 'Student',
       @pPassword = '123456',
       @ResponseMessage = @ResponseMessage OUTPUT

SELECT @ResponseMessage AS N'@ResponseMessage'
```

As a result, when I `SELECT` from the `[User]` table, the special Unicode letter (like 'ầ','ệ','ị',...) is expressed as "?"

I think that the problem lies in the `INSERT` statement as the table can still store `NVARCHAR` correctly when I edit it manually.

[The Result will look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ui9f.png)

Comment: `EXEC ... @pFirstName =  N'Trần Triệu'...` you **need** the `N`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're probably running your SELECT in SQL Management Studio.  Your default font for Grid Results may not be unicode-capable.  If you go into Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colours, then under "Show settings for" choose "Grid Results, you can set a font that will display Unicode characters (you'll need to determine which of your installed fonts is capable of that).

I suspect that will then give you the results you expect.  (That is, essentially the data is likely inserting into your database correctly, but the current font for the Grid Results is replacing Unicode characters with "?", because it can't display them properly)

There's also another point, for the actual EXEC of the stored proc that you're doing in Management Studio, I believe you should also append N in front of your unicode strings - eg. N'Trần Triệu'.  However, that should only impact when you're running the EXEC statement with static strings.  If you've entered values into the database using other means, then the unicode values should be there - just ensure your grid results are displaying in a unicode-capable font.

Comment: Your solution to append N in front if the unicode string is correct, the problem is in the EXEC. Though I have no problem with displaying Unicode characters in SELECT.

Answer (score 0):

Thêm chữ N trước chuỗi là được bạn